# Using vscode, i am driven crazy by annoying pop hint every time when i hit Space key, How to solve this problem?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

i am driven crazy by annoying pop hint every time when I hit Space key. As shown below:

[image: intelliSense hint window show when Space key stroke]

Now, how to find out which extension or pop snippet hint is causing the issue when I hit  space key and which one to disable it ?

Comment: i am feeling the same but its not IntelliSense for mine. It's a hint for any variable or library name that it finds similar. It would be nice if a **delay** can be set instead of an instant popup hint which blocks a lot of the code

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this issue.

**Method 1:**

In VSCODE. click File > preferences > keyboard shortcuts and search for `space` you could see `space` might be wrongly assigned to some intelli sense. Click on that particular keyboard shortcut. Double click the stroke and change the shortcut.

[image]

Method 2:

Very expensive way.

Disable all extensions first and try the `space` keystroke then try enabling one by one. You will definitely find the culprit.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I solved it eventually by disable all snippet extend one bye one, then the latest extensions, found out the cause is https://github.com/bauhausr/antd-intellisense extension.

Answer (score 0):

It drives me crazy too. I just turned off Editor: Suggest On Trigger Characters and it seems to be working for me!